Azure Tenant certificate based authentication
I am creating a powershell script that creates a self signed cert and adds it to an azure tenant app registration.
I want to assign permissions to use the graph.api read permission.
I am going to use certificate based authentication I have been able to authenticate with a certificate but i still have to figure out how to add the resource group or subscription id i assume to this app registration through PS.
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject $applicationName -KeySpec KeyExchange -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

$keyValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())

$application = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName 
$objectId = $application.Id
$applicationId = $application.AppId

Write-Host "ID: $($objectId)   -   AppID: $($applicationId)"

Write-Host "Going to Sleep"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
Write-Host "Awake"

$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $applicationId -CertValue $keyValue -StartDate $cert.NotBefore -EndDate $cert.NotAfter
Start-Sleep 5

Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $objectId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "5f8c59db-677d-491f-a6b8-5f174b11ec1d"


Write-Host "Generated Thumbprint: $($cert.Thumbprint)"

# Export the certificate to a PFX file
$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilePath -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPassword -Force -AsPlainText)

Write-Host "Certificate Created and placed in: $($certFilePath)"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

Here is the error I received.
New-AzADServicePrincipal:
Line |
53 |  $sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $applicationId -CertVal …
|        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.


Can you pls edit the question by sharing the error message screenshot ?

From : -StartDate $cert.NotBefore -EndDate $cert.NotAfter  To : -StartDate Get-Date -EndDate (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

When I tried to reproduce your powershell script in my enviornment I got same error:

To resolve the error use below Powershell Script:
Creating Microsoft Entra ID Application:
$tenantId = "your_tenant_id"
$applicationName = "your_app_name"

# Create a self-signed certificate
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Subject $applicationName -KeySpec KeyExchange -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(1)

# Get the certificate thumbprint
$thumbprint = $cert.Thumbprint

# Create a new Azure AD application
$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $applicationName 


Added certificate to the application:
New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.AppId -CertValue ([System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cert.GetRawCertData())) -StartDate $cert.NotBefore -EndDate $cert.NotAfter


API Permission blade before adding the API Permission:

For adding Service Principal and  User.Read  delegated type API Permission:
 $servicePrincipal = New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId <application_id>
 
#For adding delegated type User.Read permission
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId <object_id> -ApiId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 -PermissionId e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d



Exporting Certificate:
 $certFilePath = "<FilePath>"

$certPassword = "<YourPassword>"

#Exporting certificate

$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilePath -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certPassword -Force -AsPlainText)

Write-Host "Certificate Created and placed in: $($certFilePath)"



Reference:
Create a self-signed public certificate to authenticate your application .

Thank you for your response.
I am super close.
The only thing errors now is:
Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app. -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"
PS C:\Users\Andrew> $app = Get-AzADAppPermission -ApplicationId $sp.AppId
PS C:\Users\Andrew> Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app.AppId -ApiId "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" -PermissionId "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"
Add-AzADAppPermission: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ObjectId'. Cannot convert null to type "System.Guid".

Try  Add-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId $app.Id -ApiId 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 -PermissionId e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d
Output

Thank you! for your answer, that got my past my hurdle !
